# ChildTag appears outside parentTag in TagHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I have Parent and Child TagHelper.. I have set attribute "parentTag" for Child Tag and yet it displays outside that parent Tag. How to restrict it from appearing outside parent Tag

```
 [HtmlTargetElement("TestParent")]
public class Parent: TagHelper{
}

[HtmlTargetElement("TestChild",ParentTag = "TestParent")]
public class Child : TagHelper
{
}
```

What it need is that "TestChild" should not appear outside "TestParent"

For example:

```
<TestChild value=2></TestChild>
```

Above code must throw error or should not be shown in intellisense as it not enclosed by parent Tag "Testparent"

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Can you add the cshtml with taghelpers and the html that should be generated?

Comment: <TestParent> 
         <TestChild value=2></TestChild>
</TestParent

So my requirement is that "TestChild" should not be shown by intellisense or must throw error as not recognized tag, when i give the Child tag outside parent tag like below

<TestChild value=2></TestChild> // Not enclosed by parent tag

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your scenario with parent tag helper

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("TestParent")]
public class ParentTagHelper : TagHelper
{

}
```

and a child tag helper:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("TestChild", ParentTag = "TestParent")]
public class ChildTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Content.SetContent(Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

I added those two in `_ViewImports.cshtml`, then build the project. Then i called the tag helpers in a view:

```html
<TestParent>
    <TestChild value="101"></TestChild>
</TestParent>

<TestChild value="202"></TestChild>
```

I saw expected IntelliSense on first tag and didn't see one on the other one:

[image]

Finally, I executed the web app on ASP.NET Core 2.2. The HTML code of resulted page was:

```html
<TestParent>
    <TestChild>101</TestChild>
</TestParent>

<TestChild value="202"></TestChild>
```

It looks perfectly fine. Just as expected. The first tag was processed, the second one wasn't.

#### Conclusion

It looks like you had other problems aside from those described in original question. Most likely the problem wasn't in the sole tag helpers functionality and their restrictions on parent tags.